# OAuth authentication like Facebook

Tags: javascript, oauth

I need to authenticate by OAuth to some sites (e. g. flickr) by Javascript and I want to make experience similar to what Facebook login-button does. When you click login-button a popup window is opened, you authenticate and then popup window is closed and onlogin event of login-button is raised.

Is there any Javascript library which implements this behavior for OAuth?

Answer (score 9):

This is a feature of OAuth 2.0, which specifies a client-side flow which facilitates this.

The spec is [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-26#section-4.2) and Google's implementation of it is described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#clientside).

Support for this is included in the [google-api-javascript-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) (for Google APIs and login) and there is a general library that will work with supported providers called [gwt-oauth2](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/) -- it's written in GWT, but is also usable in a standard JavaScript environment.

edit: [Microsoft's Live Connect library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx) appears to support this flavor of OAuth 2.0 as well.

Unfortunately, Flickr does not appear to have support for this, as it [only seems to support OAuth 1.0a](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html).

But there some popular providers that do support the client-side OAuth 2.0 flow:

- Google
- Facebook
- Foursquare
- Instagram
- DailyMotion
- Windows Live

You could run your own server to make OAuth 1.0a requests to Flickr and send back OAuth 2.0 access tokens to the JavaScript client, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

I am certain [janrain](http://janrain.com/) offers authentication to sevaral sites using node.js, I would give it a peek. Also try this [example](http://derek.io/blog/2010/how-to-secure-oauth-in-javascript/)

Comment: I have done some successful tests using the janrain RPXnow product with just JavaScript.  However, we combined this with a locally server-side generated token to try to secure it slightly better.